# My simulation is slower with multthreading than in loop

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have the following stock price simulation that I am running for 40 years (= 10400 prices):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
import itertools
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from timeit import default_timer as timer

def stock_simulation(k, runs):
    start = timer()
    stock_vals = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date'], index = [-1])
    stock_val = stock_calc(100, 0, 0)
    stock_vals = stock_val
    j = 1
    for i in range(runs):
        risky_return = mu + (sigma * random.gauss(0,1))
        bonus = random.gauss(0,1)

        stock_val = stock_calc(stock_val['stock_val'], risky_return, bonus)
        stock_vals = stock_vals.append(stock_val)
        j = j + 1

    end = timer()
    print('Iteration ' + str(k) + ' took: ' + str(round(end - start, 2)))

def stock_calc(old_val, perf_risky, bonus):
    stock = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date'], index = [1])
    stock['date'] = 1

    stock['stock_val'] = (1 + perf_risky) * old_val + bonus * old_val
    return(stock)

#Simulation
exp_return = 0.05
exp_vola = 0.08
trading_days = 260
mu = exp_return / trading_days
sigma = exp_vola * np.sqrt(1 / trading_days)
print('Enter the number of runs')
NoOfRuns = input()
print('Es werden ' + str(NoOfRuns) + ' Simulationen durchgeführt.')
T = int(NoOfRuns)

#Multithreading
total_start = timer()
pool = ThreadPool(4)
pool.starmap(stock_simulation, zip(range(T), itertools.repeat(10400)))
pool.close() 
pool.join()
total_end = timer()
print(str(T) + ' were run in total and it took: ' + str(round(total_end - total_start, 2)))


total_start = timer()
for k in range(T):
    stock_simulation(k + T, 10400)
total_end = timer()
print(str(T) + ' were run in total and it took: ' + str(round(total_end - total_start, 2)))
```

After running it a few times, the multithreading version is about 12% slower than the loop version. I have no idea why this is the case. I can't multithread the longer loop because it runs 10400 times using the previous iteration.

Comment: Have you tried using a ProcessPool, as due to the GIL, threading does not increase processing, only responsiveness.

Comment: Do you have an example on how to implement this? I am a novice to multithreading and googling spits out `Pool.apply_async`. But I would need help.

Comment: Replace TheadPool with Pool, and that should be it.

Comment: I've done that and it still runs. I only did 4 runs, so it's definitely a lot slower now.

Comment: Multithreading is only effective if the threads are I/O bound because only then will the GIL will be released and other threads get a chance to run. Otherwise it just adds overhead that wouldn't be there otherwise.

Comment: @Spurious How many CPU cores do you have, as that gave me a 2x speed boost.

Comment: @matsjoyce I have 4 CPUs. How many do you have? And when you ran the code, how many runs did you do?

Comment: @martineau what is I/O bound (I read up on it a little bit and not sure if my code fits the criteria)? Can I integrate that in any form?

Comment: @Spurious Same, but I commented the pandas section out as I haven't got it installed. Shouldn't make a difference, so I'm not sure why you're not seeing a speed up.

Comment: Spurious: It means processing that involves I/O which blocks until it completes, such as reading and writing a file. Not sure what you mean by integrating it in any form.

Comment: @matsjoyce It's weird. I ran it all night and there is still a difference of about 10% in speed.

Comment: @martineau: I think I'm too much of a novice to understand your point. I meant by implementing that I was under the impression I had not included something in my code which caused something. But I know understand what you're saying. Do you disagree with the notion that a simulation is an I/O bound process?

Comment: Doubtful unless it's processing a lot data to do it. The opposite of an I/O bound task is a computationally bound one, which spends all or most of its time computing things that are only stored in memory if at all (vs being written to disk or transmitted somewhere).

Comment: @matsjoyce I ran it for 6 hours and it didn't do anything, It went into a loop and thus didn't have any output. The Pool thing doesn't work unfortunately. The Dummy version works but is slower and the sequential one works the fastest. This is weird.

Comment: @martineau OK so maybe my process is not really useful for multithreading since most of the computing is sequential by nature.

Comment: Spurious: Computationally bound tasks may benefit from multi**processing** (vs multithreading) because it spawns separate processes which each have with their own independent Python interpreters, so GIL locking is a non-issue. The downsides are that spawning a separate process itself involves somewhat more overhead than starting a thread, and any data sharing among the tasks is more complicated since each executes in its own memory space—so there'll be some additional overhead for that depending on how much of it is required. The main upside is that each task will run on a separate CPU core.

Comment: Do you two reckon if I tried to write the code in Cython it would improve both the sequential as well as the multithreaded version?

Comment: @matsjoyce could you tell me what you used instead of `pandas`? I have the suspicion that `pandas` is the cause of all the mess.

Comment: The reason this is so slow is due to the `pd.DataFrame`. The `stock_vals = stock_vals.append(stock_val)` line makes it incredibly slow. I now use lists and extend them and later convert to `DataFrame`. The multithreading is still not faster but at least the iteration is `30x` faster.

Comment: You could try using numpy instead, that should be faster. Does you list version get a performance boost by using Pool instead of ThreadPool?

Comment: Pool ended for me in an endless loop. I could not get any results. I ran it for an entire night and woke up to no results. I changed `pool = ThreadPool(4)` to `pool = Pool(4)` and imported `from multiprocessing.pool import Pool`. Was that correct?